# Extracting Embedded Objects to save locally, Unable to get Object property of OLEObject class Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform in excel 365 that can take file attachments. It embeds the selected files into a worksheet with the following code:

```
'puts file list entries into array
If DE_Form.AttachedFiles_List.ListCount > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To DE_Form.AttachedFiles_List.ListCount - 1
        ReDim Preserve FileNameArray(0 To i)
        FileNameArray(i) = DE_Form.AttachedFiles_List.List(i)
    Next i
End If

'adds icons for attached files to dc worksheet
For i = 0 To UBound(FileNameArray)
    'choose an icon based on filename extension
    'get all after last "." in filename
    FNExtension = Right(FileNameArray(i), Len(FileNameArray(i)) - _
                InStrRev(FileNameArray(i), "."))
 
    'select icon based on filename extension
    Select Case UCase(FNExtension)
    Case Is = "TXT"
      iconToUse = "C:\Windows\system32\packager.dll"

    Case Is = "XLS", "XLSM", "XLSX"
      iconToUse = "C:\Windows\Installer\{91140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe"

    Case Is = "PDF"
      iconToUse = "C:\Windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-1033-F400-7761-000000000004}\_PDFFile.ico"

    Case Else
      'this is a generic icon
      iconToUse = "C:\Windows\system32\packager.dll"
    End Select
    
    dc.Cells(GetLastRow(dc), 32 + i).ColumnWidth = 10
    dc.Cells(5, 32 + i).value = "Attached File " & i + 1
    dc.Cells(5, 32 + i).WrapText = True
    
    dc.Cells(GetLastRow(dc), 32 + i).value = FileNameArray(i)
    
    Set j = dc.OLEObjects.Add(fileName:=FileNameArray(i), _
                                link:=False, _
                                DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                                IconFileName:=iconToUse, _
                                IconIndex:=0, _
                                IconLabel:=FileNameArray(i))
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With j
        '.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Top = dc.Cells(GetLastRow(dc), 32 + i).Top
        .Left = dc.Cells(GetLastRow(dc), 32 + i).Left
        .Width = dc.Cells(GetLastRow(dc), 32 + i).Width
        .Height = dc.Cells(GetLastRow(dc), 32 + i).Height
    End With
    
Next i
```

I am trying to pull out the embedded files and save them to disk. I am also making an entry in an access database for each file. I can't save the files. I can open them (activate and I have also used the `.verb xlprimary` to open) but not save. I'd like to not use a bunch of `SendKeys` statements. I have tried using the indexes as references (this code does not), I'm activating the object first. I'm doing or have tried everything I can find on google. I keep getting an error. 'Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class'. I appreciate any help/advise. Thank you!

```
Dim NewCon As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset2, rsattach As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fn() As String, fpath As String
Dim nfle As Object

'finds file objects and sets insert statement
For i = 6 To GetLastRow(ldc)
    For j = 32 To ldc.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For Each k In ldc.OLEObjects
            k.Activate
                
            Select Case k.name
            Case Right(k.name, 6) = "Button", Right(k.name, 4) = "Icon":
            
            Case Else:
            
            If k.Left = ldc.Cells(i, j).Left Then
            
            Set NewCon = OpenDatabase("\\MyAccessDB.accdb")
            Set rs = NewCon.OpenRecordset("AttachedFiles", dbOpenTable)
            
            rs.AddNew
            
            rs.Fields("ProgramID") = ldc.Cells(i, "a").value
            fn = Split(ldc.Cells(i, j).Text, "\")
            rs.Fields("filename") = fn(UBound(fn))
            k.name = fn(UBound(fn))
            
            fpath = "\\MyFolderLocation\" & _
                k.name
            
            k.Object.SaveAs fpath                'Error is here
            
            rs.Fields("FileLocation") = fpath
            rs.Fields("Modified On") = ldc.Cells(i, "ae").value
            
            End If
            End Select
        Next k
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: After some more researching, I think the problem is because I'm not using file type as I embed the oleobject. Continuing to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not a full answer to the question, but far too long for a comment and I thought may help ... replace your line `k.Object.SaveAs fpath` with

```
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = k.ShapeRange(1)
If shp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
    Debug.Print shp.OLEFormat.progID ' for info
    If shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "Excel*" Then
        shp.OLEFormat.Verb XlOLEVerb.xlVerbOpen
        Dim wkb As Workbook
        Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
        wkb.SaveAs "C:\test\" & shp.Name & wkb.FileFormat ' change to your folder
        wkb.Close
    ElseIf shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "Acrobat*" Then
        ' do Acrobat stuff ... I don't have the Acrobat library
    ElseIf shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "Package*" Then
        shp.OLEFormat.Verb XlOLEVerb.xlVerbPrimary
        ' do Notepad stuff with SendKeys or Windows API?
    Else
        Debug.Print "Unknown ProgID '" & shp.OLEFormat.progID & "'"
    End If
Else
    Debug.Print shp.Name & " is not an embedded OLEObject"
End If
```

Needs code for Acrobat and Notepad, as per comments, but saves Excel files correctly. Definitely needs error handling!

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. I'll adapt for the other file types.

Comment: This very much sets up how to get this done. I'll post the solution in a couple of days. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code I wound up with. Not totally finished but y'all get the idea. Thanks again @JohnM

```
'finds file objects and sets insert statement
For Each k In ldc.OLEObjects
     'saves file to sharedrive
    k.Activate
    Set shp = k.ShapeRange(1)
            
    If shp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
    
        'gets row and column of the object's address
        adrs = Split(shp.TopLeftCell.Address, "$")
        j = ldc.Range(adrs(1) & "1").Column
        i = adrs(2)
            
        Set NewCon = OpenDatabase("\\Server\Access.accdb")
        Set rs = NewCon.OpenRecordset("AttachedFiles", dbOpenTable)
            
        rs.AddNew
            
        rs.Fields("ID") = ldc.Cells(i, "a").value
        fn = Split(ldc.Cells(i, j).Text, "\")
        rs.Fields("filename") = fn(UBound(fn))
            
        fpath = "\\Server\MyFolder\"
            
        rs.Fields("FileLocation") = fpath
        rs.Fields("Modified On") = ldc.Cells(i, "ae").value
        
        'new path for object
        ldc.Cells(i, j).value = fpath & k.name
            
        'saves file to sharedrive
        
        Debug.Print shp.OLEFormat.progID ' for info
                
        Select Case True
                
        Case shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "Excel*":
            shp.OLEFormat.Verb XlOLEVerb.xlVerbOpen
                        
            Set wkb = GetObject("Worksheet in " & ThisWorkbook.name, "Excel.Application")
            wkb.SaveAs fileName:=fpath & shp.name
            wkb.Close
                    
        Case shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "Acrobat*":
            ChDir ("\\Server\Myfolder\")
                        
            shp.OLEFormat.Verb XlOLEVerb.xlVerbPrimary
            
            Set wrd = GetObject(, "AcroExch.App")
            
            'Send Keys method:
            wrd.Application.SendKeys "+^(s)", True 'Saves
            'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")
                    
            wrd.Application.SendKeys shp.name, True 'Attempts to send new file name but doesn't.
            'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")
                    
            wrd.Application.SendKeys "~", True
            'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")
                    
            wrd.Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True 'closes the reader.
            'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")
                
        Case shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "Word*", shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "textfile*":
            shp.OLEFormat.Verb XlOLEVerb.xlVerbOpen
                        
            Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
                        
            Set wrdfle = wrd.Documents("Document in " & ThisWorkbook.name)
                        
            wrdfle.SaveAs fpath & shp.name
            wrd.Application.Quit
                    
        Case shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "PowerPoint*":
            shp.OLEFormat.Verb XlOLEVerb.xlVerbOpen
                        
            Set wrd = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
                    Set wrdfle = wrd.activepresentation
                        
            wrdfle.SaveAs fpath & shp.name
            wrdfle.Close
                
        Case shp.OLEFormat.progID Like "Package*":
            shp.OLEFormat.Verb XlOLEVerb.xlVerbPrimary
            ' do Notepad stuff with SendKeys or Windows API?
        Case Else:
            Debug.Print "Unknown ProgID '" & shp.OLEFormat.progID & "'"
        End Select
    NewCon.Close
    End If
Next k
```